How can I make my video on expo full screen. I am using expo-av
Currently using expo av library to render videos on my react native expo app.
I cant make my video go full screen.
On the docs it is said that i should use the presentFullscreenPlayer method like so:
        await videoRef.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer(); // Trigger fullscreen immediately

as you can see in the below function called playVideo. But that is not working.
Please assist
Here is my code:
Video.jsx file
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { COLORS, FONTS, icons } from '../constants'
import { router } from 'expo-router'
import { ResizeMode, Video } from "expo-av";
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalProvider'

// Get device screen dimensions
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default function Videos({title, date, banner, index, videoLink, sourceLogo}) {
    const { setActiveArticle } = useGlobalContext();
    const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
    const bannerImage = `https://${banner}`;
    const videoBorders = (index !== 3) ? { borderBottomWidth: 0.2, borderBottomColor: COLORS.subText } : { borderBottomWidth: 0 };
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

    const playVideo = async () => {
        await videoRef.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer(); // Trigger fullscreen immediately
        setPlay(true); // Update `play` after fullscreen activation
        console.log(play, videoLink);
    }
    
    
    return (
        <>
            <>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={playVideo} key={index} style={[styles.container, videoBorders]}>

                {
                    play ? (
                        <View style={{ width: 150, height: 100 }}>
                            <Video
                            source={{ uri: 'https://videos.pexels.com/video-files/4114797/4114797-uhd_2560_1440_25fps.mp4' }}
                            ref={videoRef}
                            style={styles.fullscreenVideo}
                            resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
                            useNativeControls
                            shouldPlay
                            onFullscreenUpdate={({fullscreenUpdate, status}) => {
                                console.log(fullscreenUpdate, status)
                                switch (fullscreenUpdate) {
                                  case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_PRESENT: 
                                    console.log(' the fullscreen player is about to present');
                                    break;
                                  case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_PRESENT: 
                                    console.log('the fullscreen player just finished presenting');
                                    break;
                                  case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_DISMISS: 
                                    console.log('the fullscreen player is about to dismiss');
                                    break;
                                  case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_DISMISS: 
                                    console.log('the fullscreen player just finished dismissing');
                                }
                              }}
                            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => {
                                if (status.didJustFinish) {
                                  setPlay(false);
                                }
                              }}
                        />
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <ImageBackground
                            source={{ uri: bannerImage}}
                            imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 7 }}
                            style={styles.banner}
                        >
                            <View style={styles.overlay} />
                            <Image
                                source={icons.play}
                                style={styles.play}
                            />
                            
                        </ImageBackground>
                    )
                }
          
                <View style={styles.videoInfo}>
                    <Text style={styles.firstVideoHeading} numberOfLines={3}>{ title }</Text>
                    <View style={styles.subHeadingWrapper}>
                        <Image
                          source={sourceLogo}
                          style={styles.sourceLogo}
                          // resizeMode='cover'
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.firstVideoSubHeading}>433 • { date } </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        
            {(index === 3) && (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => router.push({ pathname: '/news/News' })}
                  style={styles.showMore}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.showMoreText}>Show More</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            </>
        </>
    )
}

On the docs it is said that i should use the presentFullscreenPlayer method like so:
        await videoRef.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer(); // Trigger fullscreen immediately

as you can see in the below function called playVideo. But that is not working.
